# Tableau : Update external file in published twbx (Package Workbook)

Tags: tableadapter, tableau-api

We have a packaged workbook which is going to publish on client machines. As part of the package we have one external file which needs to updated (not refresh) with new data (File format will remain same) quarterly.

And the problem comes here my team dont want to go into maintenance  mode. So they want the user to update the external file quarterly.
Is it possible for the user to access the file in the published data source in server and upload a new file when ever it is available ? 
We are not much aware of the client file system so we are not going for option of placing it in tableau repository. And we dont want to upload the file as part of the DB (Has to be a external file).

Please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options. In all cases described, you should separate the workbook from the data and publish a workbook, not a packaged workbook (i.e. don't check the include files button)

Briefly, you can put the file on a share drive but it must be accessible from Tableau Server using the Run As User account via exactly the same path used to publish. That is kind of brittle and can have security issues if not careful.

You could create an extract and publish the data separately as a Tableau Data Source, and then use the Tableau Data Extract Command Utility to refresh and publish the updated extract when desired. http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/help.htm#extracting_TDE.html%3FTocPath%3DSet%2520Up%2520Data%2520Sources%7CExtract%2520Data%7C_____6

That will work on Windows only.

Or you could use the Tableau Data Extract API (or SDK now) to generate the extract from a script and then publish it using the REST API. That approach will work on just about any system.

Or you could use a database. Almost any database.